# How do I add parameters/settings to my socket room?

Tags: express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to add parameters/settings to my socket room on top of the default room (roomid)
I've tried to read up on socket.io docs and looked up online but I couldn't find much help

I initialize a new game room id and join the room with the code snippet below

```
let newRoom = `A ${colors[rando[0]]} ${animals[rando[1]]}`
socket.join(newRoom)
```

I tried:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms[newRoom].roomSetting = "foo"
```

I'm using socket.io v4!

Comment: The room object in socket.io is not meant to be accessible to you and will be gone the moment there are no sockets in the room any more.  It is probably better to store your room settings somewhere else in your own data structures rather than try to use some un-documented way of getting access to a room object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, I did end up storing my own room settings and kept it up to date with the socket rooms by adding/removing rooms whether or not it's created/destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up initializing my own room object where each room has settings attached to it. Spent too much time trying to figure out socket rooms but I guess things are un-documented for a reason. Lesson learned!

```
const rooms = {};
```

After initializing the rooms remove any dead/destroyed rooms,

```
function getActiveRooms(rooms) {
    const arr = Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
    const filtered = arr.filter(room => !room[1].has(room[0]))
    const res = filtered.filter(i => i[1].size === 1);
    const r = res.map(r => r[0])

    // loop through rooms and remove rooms that are not in r
    // and store someSettings value in an array
    const someSetting = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(rooms)) {
        if (!r.includes(key)) {
            delete rooms[key]
        } else {
            someSetting.push(value.someSetting)
        }
    }


    return ([r, someSettings]);
}
```

Output would be something like...

```
["roomName", "someSetting1", "someSetting2" ...etc]
```